# PC starts, shuts down, then continues to run

Tags: motherboard, bios, boot, shutdown

I just assembled my new desktop. This is the configuration:

- MB: ASUS Maximus VI Gene
- CPU: i7-4771
- RAM: 16GB DDR3 Kingston (2x 8GB)
- HDD: Seagate 4TB
- PSU: Raidmax RX-600AF
- GPU: on-board graphics

When I start the machine, the fans start spinning (the one on the processor is really loud) for a few seconds, then it shuts down and then it starts again continuing to boot normally. What could be the cause of this (I am assuming this is not normal)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not normal. Test if it happens with lower power consumption (pull out all usb, the hard disk, the dvd). If it fixes, buy a larger   power. If not, make a bios upgrade/flash rewrite. If it doesn't helps too, you need to live with it or buy a new motherboard.

Comment: I solved it. I plugged the wrong PSU cable in the MB.